What will happen if I call `allocate_at_least(0)` according to C++23 standard?
As shown here, the behavior of allocate(0) is unspecified.
So, what will happen if I call allocate_at_least(0) according to C++23 standard? Is the behavior implementation-defined, or will it be treated as allocate(a_non_zero_value)?

unspecified behavior • behavior, for a well-formed program construct and correct data, that depends on the implementation.  Hence, it is implementation defined, but the implementation is not required to document the behavior.  At my house, we call that "you get what you get and you don't throw a fit" — usually for the kids when they don't want to eat their vegetables.

[allocator.requirements.general]/44 specifies (emphasis mine):

Returns: allocation_result<XX::pointer, XX::size_type>{ptr, count} where ptr is memory allocated for an array of count T and such an object is created but array elements are not constructed, such that count ≥ n. If n == 0, the return value is unspecified.

Thus, the behaviour, just like allocate(0), is unspecified.
